# nobody user/group with NIS/NFS

Tags: permissions, nfs, nis, nobody, yp

**Software overview**

**Machine A**(NIS server): CentOS 6.2

**Machine B**:(NFS server) CentoS 6.2

**Client machines:** OpenSuse 12.3, CentOS 6.4 and CentOS 5.6

**Introduction and setup**

Machine **A** is an NIS server which serves a group of client machines. Home directories, as defined by the NIS mapping, come from an NFS server (machine **B**) are mounted automatically on login.

Machine **B** is an NFS server which authenticates using NIS.

When I log in to a client machine I can read/write to my home directory and all files therein are

```
alex users
```

in terms of permission. The same is true when I log into the NFS server.

*HOWEVER* when I log into the NIS server, my home directory mounts, I can write files to it, but all files appear as

```
nobody nobody
```

for permission. Despite this `whoami` yeilds `alex`

**Test: Creating files on the NIS server in the /home/alex directory**

If I create a file in my home directory while logged in to the NIS server

```
touch /home/alex/testfile 
ls -l testfile # on server

-rw-r--r--. 1 nobody nobody 0 Mar 19 14:21 testfile
```

but if I run `ls -l` on a client machine I get

```
ls -l testfile # on client machine
-rw-r--r--. 1 alex users 0 Mar 19 14:21 testfile
```

So clearly the file is being created as the correct user and permissions are being respected on the NIS server. Other than displaying my files as `nobody nobody` everything appears fine, but I'm worried this may be a symptom of something more serious.

**Test: `ypcat` commands**

When logged in to the NIS server I can run

```
ypcat passwd
```

and get output.

However `ypcat shadow` yields

```
 No such map shadow. Reason: Internal NIS error
```

But I would have thought this was because I have

```
MERGE_PASSWD=true
```

Set in my `/var/yp/Makefile`

**Unwanted password redundancy**

As a final weird twist - for *some* users, they're able to log in via NIS using old passwords which should no longer work. I have no idea how this would happen because there's only a single entry per user in the /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow? This may be an unrelated issue, or may provide useful information.

Comment: are you sure that you run rpc.idmapd on the servers?

Comment: rpc.idmapd is running everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are mounting nfsv3 on client machines and nfsv4 on Machine B (nis server)

If you are using autofs to mount home directories add the -nfsvers=3 option at Machine B

Answer (score 1):

Gustavo's answer was basically correct, but I thought I'd add some detail her rather than as a comment

I'm mounted as nsf4 everywhere, but for some reason nsf4 isn't working on the NIS server.

Adding `defaultvers=3,nfsvers=3` to the mountline in auto.master followed by service such that my auto.master file looks like this

```
#
# Sample auto.master file
# This is an automounter map and it has the following format
# key [ -mount-options-separated-by-comma ] location
# For details of the format look at autofs(5).
#
/misc   /etc/auto.misc
#
# NOTE: mounts done from a hosts map will be mounted with the
#       "nosuid" and "nodev" options unless the "suid" and "dev"
#       options are explicitly given.
#
/net    -hosts
#
# Include central master map if it can be found using
# nsswitch sources.
#
# Note that if there are entries for /net or /misc (as
# above) in the included master map any keys that are the
# same will not be seen as the first read key seen takes
# precedence.
#
+auto.master
/home   yp:auto.home    -rw,hard,bg,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,defaultvers=3,nfsvers=3
```

Followed by an autofs restart

```
service autofs restart
```

Got things up and running.

One random issue - I'd physically logged in to the machine in our data center but not logged out, so the administrator user `/home` directory failed to be remounted even after a restart, which caused some confusion.